# Direct property binding updates, DataContext binding doesn't

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am binding the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` to an `ObservableCollection` that is a property of a property of the ViewModel; to be exact to its length via this `ValueConverter`:

```cs
public class EnumerableToCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (null == value ? 0 : ((IEnumerable<object>)value).Count());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works fine and updates properly when the collection changes with the following XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SubViewModel.Collection, Converter={StaticResource EnumerableToCountConverter}}" />
```

Now, because I also need the reference elsewhere, I want to have the collection as the control's `DataContext` and use a relative binding path:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SubViewModel.Collection}"
           Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumerableToCountConverter}}" />
```

This only works partially - the value is set correctly initially, but never updated when the collection changes.

What am I missing here? How can I still get this to update with the changes in the collection?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "collection changes": collection items added/removed or a new collection assigned? Second question: why don't you just bind your `TextBlock.Text` to `SubViewModel.Collection.Count`?

Comment: Yes, items are added or removed; the collection stays the same. I didn't bind to `Count` simply because I didn't think of it - of course, that's possible, and it actually appears to solve the problem, as it updates correctly when the collection is set as the `DataContext`. So, if you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment to original question, you could bind your `TextBlock.Text` dependency property directly to the collection's `Count` property, so you don't need any converter. And since the `ObservableCollection` implementation raises the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Count` property, you should get your binding target updated.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SubViewModel.Collection}" Text="{Binding .Count}" />
```